# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, …' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I am using SharePoint server 2013 installed on one server and vs 2010 on my local PC.  I have install the "WSPBuilder" to develop the web-parts on my local PC. I have develop the one test web-part. The web part is successfully build and generated .wsp file.  But when I Right click on project -> WSPBuilder -> Delploy, then I am getting the below error.

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Can any one help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not have SharePoint on your development machine the wspbuilder will not be able to find it's dependent dll:s from SharePoint!

Is there anything stopping you from installing visual studio and wspbuilder on the SharePoint server?